# De los 2 formularios, el que dice ¿quieres eliminarle? desaparece automáticamente al pulsar el botón submit

Tags: php, html

Tengo una función, en la que evalúo si un un usuario existe, en cuyo caso quiero que aparecezcan 2 botones. Uno para eliminar (sí) y otro para que no lo elimine (no).

Si yo ejecuto esto tal cual, me funciona perfectamente, tal y como quiero.

```
<body>
        <h2>Cambiospassword</h2>
        <form method="POST" action="">
            Introduce su nombre de usuario o email <br/>
            Nombre de usuario <input type="text" name="btnombre" value=""/><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="btenviar" value="Solicitar Clave"/><br/>
            <br/>
        </form>
        <?php echo buscar_usuario('diego');?>
    </body>
```

Sin embargo, si lo hago de esta otra forma, el ejercicio no funciona:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            <title>recuperarpassword.php</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Cambiospassword</h2>
        <form method="POST" action="">
            Introduce su nombre de usuario o email <br/>
            Nombre de usuario <input type="text" name="btnombre" value=""/><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="btenviar" value="Solicitar Clave"/><br/>
            <br/>
        </form>
        <?php
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset($_POST['btenviar'])){
            $usuario=$_POST['btnombre'];
            echo $usuario;
            echo buscar_usuario($usuario);
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

El problema es que cuando pulso por ejemplo, el botón *si*, me desaparece el el formulario por completo y no se muestra "has elegido si". Tan solo funciona si no compruebo con `$_POST` y le paso directamente el valor por defecto.

Comment: Por favor, explica un poco mejor tu problema, arregla tu pregunta añadiendo más información textual, no tanto código, explica con mejor y mayor palabras tu problema para que podamos ayudar, sobre todo, ese código que no se puede leer

Comment: hola, gracias por responder. He intentado explicarlo aunque la mejor opción sería poner el código completo, pero no me deja stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

**Este es el código de las funciones**

```
function buscar_usuario($usuario){
    try{
        $conexion = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=(local);Database=ACL");
        $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        //usuario
        $sentencia_usuario="select uName from dbo.Usuarios where uName='$usuario'";
        $comp_user=$conexion->query($sentencia_usuario)->fetchColumn();
        if($comp_user){
            echo "EL usuario existe <br/>";
                //echo eliminar();

                echo "¿ Quieres eliminarle ?<br/>";
                print "<form method='POST' action=''>";
                    echo "<input type='submit' name='btsi' value='si'/>";
                    echo "<input type='submit' name='btno' value='no'/>";
                print "</form>";
                echo " <br/>";   

                if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && (isset($_POST['btsi']))){
                    $boton_si=$_POST['btsi'];
                    echo "Has elegido si --- $boton_si ";
                }elseif($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && (isset($_POST['btno']))){
                    $boton_no=$_POST['btno'];
                    echo "Has elegido no ------ $boton_no";
                }else{
                    "No has pulsado nada";
                }


        }else{
            echo "No existe el ususario $usuario";
        }
    
        }catch(PDOException $ex){
            echo "Error al conectar con la base de datos ACL <br/>";
            echo "Motivo <br/>";
            echo "Error". $ex->getCode(). "<br/> Mensaje: ". $ex->getMessage()."";
        }finally{
            $conexion=null;
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Por lo que veo @juscasmarcastilla tienes creado un formulario creado dentro de la función php, pero con el action vacío. Si tienes el action vacío, el formulario al ser enviado hará cosas raras, se podrá enviar o no, o se enviará pero recargará la web, o también hará un intento se submit y en este caso, quizas te esté haciendo el desaparecer tu formulario. También te digo como consejo, que evites a toda costa, mezclar el html con el php de esa forma que estás haciendo. Actualmente ya no se programa así, o por lo menos se debe de evitar.

Comment: @juancasmarcastilla Quizás sería bueno hacer un include de un archivo dentro de esa función que contenga el formulario html o también quitar de ahí esa creación del formulario y hacer una función con el formulario por separado y hacer la llamada. Pero lo que sería mejor de todo es crearte un fichero para tu conexión donde en ese fichero tienes los datos de conexion y luego un html que llame a un chivo php que haga el action que quieres

Comment: Muchas gracaias @scorpions78, lo tendré en cuenta